# Ideas for a security framework for DevOps

Tags: devops

I am trying to put together a security control framework based on people process and technology for DevOps operating practices  - what controls do you think must be included?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Can you give any more details?

Comment: please lookup the term: DevSecOps